Concurrent, identical instances as an integration test
Over the years it's becoming clear to me what's an integration test and what's a unit-test.
I understand some people more or less settle on their definitions but to be brief I consider testing one class, that does one thing, a unit - if it's tests are deterministic, rapid to cook-up and don't touch anything crossing it's own process instead just testing business logic of that unit in-memory - it's a "done" deal; I call that unit-testing.
But this class I'm cooking up messes with events, it emits and receives them.
A unit test I'm setting up deals with a scenario where 2 instances of the same class are running side-by-side; making sure each instance is only receiving the events it's meant to receive.
By my own definition I'm unit-testing. On the other hand, this feels like I'm doing integration-testing, integrating my unit, with it's itself.
Am I still unit-testing and if not, why?
The reason I'm asking is that I run my test-suites so many times per-day, introducing brittleness or slow tests tends to snowball and I'd like to avoid this pitfall.

How did you wire up event handling? There’s probably some other component involved, right? Secondly, you’re asking about how to call this test, but in your last paragraph you’re talking about brittle and slow tests. How you call a test does not make it brittle or slow. I mean, if you have a slow test, calling it a unit test doesn’t make it faster.

Does it matter if it's a unit test or an integration test or something else? I've realized that terms like "unit", "integration", and "system" aren't the best way to think about testing. I've started to favor Brian Marick's testing quadrants, which were expanded on in Crispin and Gregory's Agile Testing. I see more value in discussing who the test helps and how it helps them.

@ThomasOwens Not sure - I only care if it's slow, brittle or too broad (hence non-descriptive of the requirements) at the end of the day. I just settled on the terms because these criteria tend to fit in those boxes.

Already established in another answer, the "unit" in unit test does not exclusively refer to a single class. Sometimes a handful of classes work together as a unit, at which point they can be tested in unison.
More importantly, however:

A unit test I'm setting up deals with a scenario where 2 instances of the same class (Foo) are running side-by-side; making sure each instance is only receiving the events it's meant to receive.

That's not a test of Foo, that's a test of the load balancer of Foo, who for all intents and purposes is an external consumer of a Foo instance (instances, in this case).
Edit: I'm calling it a load balancer for lack of a better name. Load balancers imply that it equally distributes events to instances. There might be a different reason for deciding which instance to assign an event to. That distinction is irrelevant for this answer, so I'm just going to refer to it as a load balancer and leave it at that.
Such a test does not require a real instance of Foo. It can be swapped out with a mock that records what events it's being given.
The proof is in the pudding: Foo does not control which events it receives. Therefore, a test that focuses on the reception of events is not testing a responsibility of Foo, it's testing the responsibility of whoever is giving the events to the Foo instance.

Am I still unit-testing and if not, why?

For a different reason than you're arguing, you are definitely unit testing this. Having multiple Foo instances is a red herring, because they can be mocked for the purpose of this test and they are actually not the unit under test in the first place.
The unit under test here is the load balancer, and therefore yes this is a unit test.

As an aside, don't get too caught up with the nomenclature between unit and integration tests. It's important to understand these concepts and that they each have different benefits and drawbacks. It's less important to be able to label each test accurately and definitively, especially when considering intra-application integration tests vs unit tests.

That's a good point - you got me, in fact there's a Bus that transmits the events and in essence that's what I'm testing, now that I think about it - even if indirectly.

@nicholaswmin: Regardless of whether that bus is a networked component or an in-memory instance in the same runtime as the Foo instances, you should be able to design a unit test around the bus that merely captures what it would be talking to (if this weren't a unit test).

Absolutely, that's true - In this case I'll hold off, my personal judgement tells me that what I'm doing is enough (it's in-memory) and I don't like mocks either - but at the end of the day the question might be moot - I wasn't unit-testing the class itself but the bus that connects them.

@nicholaswmin: For the purpose of your original goal, if you use the real bus and real Foo instances, then I would consider this an integration test, because both the bus and (individual) Foo instances are units of their own. "what I'm doing is enough (it's in-memory)" This strikes on the key point between considering integration vs unit tests. Integration tests are easier to provide wide coverage with but they provide less detail when they fail (which component failed to integrate?). Comparatively, unit tests take more time to write but tell you precisely what component failed. [..]

@nicholaswmin [..] You're not wrong that this is a matter of deciding when enough is enough. I'm merely pointing out that sometimes people get lured in by the less effort needed to write integration tests, forgetting about the lack of detailed information when that's the only test to capture a failure. At the same time, unit tests shouldn't be written dogmatically either, tests should not just be turtles all the way down. Pick what you find is appropriate, but make your decision an informed one.

Uhh I have got to up my unit-testing game; even though I'm aware of that distinction - that unit-tests isolate failure because of their proximity/specificity to the unit, and even though I am aware that I should be testing results and not implementations, I don't recall my unit-tests behaving like that = like a flashlight that says HERE. They fail in batches  and rarely isolate failure much better than an integration test would. I really like unit testing but I guess i need to be more alert when writing them

@nicholaswmin: It's possible that one bug can cause several different regressions, and the unit tests will only point out the regressions (by failing), not the specific bug itself. Think of an integration test failure as trying to start a car and it doesn't, whereas a unit test failure would tell you "exhaust vent cannot release exhaust gases". Way more helpful in terms of figuring out that someone shoved a potato in your exhaust pipe though it technically doesn't tell you that there's a potato.

The "unit" in "unit testing" isn't necessarily a class. As Wikipedia correctly states:

Unit is defined as a single behaviour exhibited by the system under test (SUT), usually corresponding to a requirement. While it may imply it's a [...] a method or a class (in object-oriented programming) it doesn't mean functions/methods, modules or classes always correspond to units. From the system-requirements perspective only the perimeter of the system is relevant, thus only entry points to externally-visible system behaviours define units.

In your specific case, it sounds like you are not testing just two instances of your class, but also something like an event gateway and that it is correctly connected to the instances. That sounds a lot like an integration test for me. On the other hand: is it possible to test the event handling of one instance of your class in isolation? That would be IMHO a unit test.
Also ask yourself: does it really matter how you call the test? If not, don't overthink this. In practice, the borders between unit testing and integration testing are not "mathematically" strict, and it is to some degree dependend from the test author what they call a unit and what not.
See also:

Unit testing vs Integration Testing


The answer I've accepted pretty much makes the same point as this. Good one @DocBrown

The outer limit for a unit test is IO. No DB, no file system, no networking. So it depends on where these events are going. If you're sending them to some event server this isn't a unit test. If you're keeping them in the local memory space where they move around blazingly fast (either by design or by mocking) then calling this a unit test is fine.
Also, two objects being run side by side can absolutely be considered one unit. It's not called object testing. It's called unit testing.

A test which requires to include external I/O is surely not a unit test, but just because a test does not require I/O, I would not conclude it is a unit test.

@DocBrown there are certainly more requirements. But being a single class is not one of them.

This answer is imprecise. While the IO boundary is definitely a boundary for a unit test, that doesn't mean it's the only boundary. There's nothing wrong with defining unit boundaries more granularly than on the IO boundaries of the application. Similarly, a test run within the IO boundaries of an application can still be considered an integration test. Effectively, it's an integration test when two or more (individually cohesive) units are being tested at the same time.

@candied_orange: If the question is "is this [single-runtime] test a unit test?" (which it is), and your answer explains how it's not a unit test when it goes across IO boundaries and it's fine to call it a unit test if it's in-memory (which it does); then the logical inference is that you're addressing the IO boundary as the boundary of when it is/isn't a unit test. This is why I called your answer imprecise instead of wrong, because I think you're aware that IO is not the only boundary for unit tests, but the answer is not addressing those points and appears to be implying otherwise.

"When I say you can’t do X that doesn’t mean I said you can do Y" is not an accurate summary of the answer stating "If you're keeping them in the local memory space [..] then calling this a unit test is fine". The part of the answer quoted here effectively states that being in-memory outright qualifies a test to be considered to be a unit test, without further modifiers added, which is simply not correct. It's correct that a test that crosses the IO boundary is definitely not a unit test. It's not correct that a test that doesn't cross the IO boundary therefore invariably is a unit test.

@candied_orange: Unless you believe that "check my answer history to find out the answer to your question" is an acceptable format for StackExchange; yes you should be answering the question at hand with the information needed to answer it. As to the link you added in your answer, its content amounts to "A test is not a unit test if [reasons]", which should not be logically inverted into "therefore everything else is invariably a unit test". This is faulty reasoning and the precise issue with this answer. It implies something that you know not to be true but can't be bothered writing.

Although admittedly I am a fan of this candied orange on this site, I do not like your definition of a unit test at all. The main reason is that they negate the primary benefit I get by each unit test which is the clarification of some aspect of my program, in my own head.

@nicholaswmin Well thank you. I certainly don't want to interfere with you achieving clarity. I hope you realize I'm not saying you can't write whatever automated tests you find useful. I'm only saying when you call them unit tests there is an expectation that they are deterministic. A fancy way to say they always do the same thing. Ensuring that comes with requirements. I'm not arguing against integration tests. I just want to call a spade a spade. I don't understand how that is harming your clarity.

I most certainly agree with you on all points. Where I disagree on categorically is the insinuation that a unit-test is defined by the process boundaries.  That would settle a debate going on for quite some time, rapidly. My understanding is that it's defined by the "unit" ... whatever that means to anyone.
I was complaining about your reduction of it's definition to a very narrow, technical  consideration.
ButI s that what you really meant, or are we misunderstanding you and pointlessly arguing?

@nicholaswmin where is this debate raging? Please point me to it. What I've experienced is there are those who have a disciplined opinion of what a unit test is and those who call it a unit test because they run it with a tool with unit in its name, like jUnit. True unit tests require a functional core. Almost every code base has some code that qualifies. To make good use of unit tests almost every code base needs stuff moved around to make a lot of the code qualify. You don't get this for free.


@nicholaswmin where is this debate raging? Right here. Exhibit A.


What I've experienced is there are those who have a disciplined opinion of what a unit test is and those who call it a unit test because they run it with a tool with unit in its name, like jUnit.

You're not giving me the credit I deserve; I'm a fanatic of unit-testing and I am aware of every single detail you're mentioned. I wholehearteadly agree with them but I don't see them as relevant to the assertion: The outer limit for a unit test is IO. It's the "unit" that is the outer limit.

@nicholaswmin A Set of Unit Testing Rules - Michael Feathers lists 5 rules. The first 3: database, network, and file system are IO. The other 2 are important as well but hard to point at in an architectural chart.

Yes, I see your point. I mean, I do the same as stated in the OP but I just don't see it as it's exclusive and definitive characteristic. Then again  thats not what you said, you only said it's the outer limit. It's Friday and I'll leave it at " i see... ok"

As for your credit, I respect anyone trying to make sense of this mess. The reason IO is a boundary is because once that involved you've lost control of side effects. The subtle problem here is once that happens it doesn't tell you. Everything will seem fine, then you commit of a Friday and a test decides to behave differently right when you want to go home.

The sentiment behind it is something that you might or might not have experienced yourself; I think it's common. There's a phase that (some) of software engineers go through in their careers, if they care about their work - and that's a phase of being incessitanglt theoretic and scientififc about stuff they shouldnt be, like stupidly applying design patterns for no reason. It is a very miserable and inflexible phase and one you feel nice exiting from. I don't want the same to happen about testing, because that's my second "big revelation" in this profession, for lack of a better word

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@nicholaswmin A pattern having a name doesn’t make it a good thing. If someone went to the trouble of making their tests deterministic and the unit functional it’d be nice if there was an easy way to say that before I screw it up.
